# Multiple Threads accessing a non synchronised Map

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I am facing this issue, I have two classes A and B , 'class A' has two Threads t1 and t2 and its trying to access 'Class B' map as below now the problem is, I can not make any changes on class B' map hence I can not use `synchronised` keyword or I can not put it in synchronised method. So my doubt is, is there any other way to synchronise this map.

```
public class A{

    static B b = new B();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Map<Integer,String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(b.getMap());
                map.put(1, "one");
                map.put(2, "two");
                map.put(3, "three");
                b.setMap(map);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Map<Integer,String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(b.getMap());
                map.put(4, "four");
                map.put(5, "five");
                map.put(6, "six");
                b.setMap(map);

            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : b.getMap().entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }     
    }
```

I am using `LinkedHashMap`, only to track the order of insertion (ignore performance issues)

```
public class B{

    private Map<Integer,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();

    public Map<Integer,String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<Integer,String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Comment: as i see, you have option to setMap exposed from B, just create concurrent hashmap in A and then set it to B.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the synchronized `Map` once and have both threads use that one `Map` instance.

```
final Map<Integer,String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(b.getMap());
b.setMap(map);

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        map.put(4, "four");
        map.put(5, "five");
        map.put(6, "six");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the map in B. If you cant use `ConcurrentHashMap` then you can use the `Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>())` instead. Any external synchronization will always leave the possibility of unsynchronized access to the map.

```
public class A{

    static B b;
    static {
        b = new B();
        b.setMap(new ConcurrentHashMap());
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: `synchronizedMap` leaves the same possibility: for example, the `keySet.iterator()` obtained from it is not synchronized, therefore it's not thread-safe, requiring external synchronization. A `ConcurrentMap` is much better in this respect, guaranteeing a stable iterator over a snapshot existing at the time of iterator acquisition/first call to `next()/hasNext()`.

Comment: Yes ConcurrentHashMap is much better, I only added the LinkedHashMap example because op stated `I am using LinkedHashMap, only to track the order of insertion`, which is not possible with CHM.

Answer (score 1):

As others indicated, you can use a synchronized wrapper, and `java.util.Collections` provides a convenient means to obtain one.  Having each thread get its own synchronized wrapper does not help you, though -- all participants need to use the same synchronization tool.

More generally, if you need to synchronize access to some less convenient object then you can use external synchronization.  In your case, that might look like this:

```
public class A{

    static B b = new B();
    // will use this object to synchronize access to b's map:
    static Object bLock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Map<Integer,String> map = b.getMap();

                synchronized(bLock) {
                    map.put(1, "one");
                    map.put(2, "two");
                    map.put(3, "three");
                }
                // no need for setMap()
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Map<Integer,String> map = b.getMap();

                synchronized (bLock) {
                    map.put(4, "four");
                    map.put(5, "five");
                    map.put(6, "six");
                }
                // no need for setMap()
            }
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```

Package java.util.concurrent.locks has some lock classes that you can use, too, but often you don't need anything so fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
public class A{

    static B b;
    static Map bMap;

    static {
        b = new B();
        bMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(b.getMap());
    }

    ... //now use bMap instead
}
```

Comment: The OP stated that _"i can not make any changes on class B' map"_